# SOQL query returns no results when using System.runAs() method

Tags: apex, unit-test, runas

In my Apex test class, I created a contact and inserted it. When running a SOQL query as an external user, the query returns an empty list.

I thought it is because the external user doesn't have access to contacts created by me. However, when I'm logged in Salesforce with this same external user, the query returns a list with contacts even though some of them are not accessible by the external user (when the external user wants to see the detail page, an error : "Insufficient permission...." is of course displayed).

Do you know a workaround so that my query doesn't return an empty list ?

Code :

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
private without sharing class myClass_TEST {     
static testMethod void myTestMethod() {        
    // Create contact (Doesn't exist in the org)
    Contact testContact = UtilityMethods.createContact();       
    insert testcontact;

    List<Contact> listContacts1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact]; // **Contains 'testContact'**      

    // Get external user (Exists in the org)
    User externalUser = [Select Id, name from User where Id='Id_Of_the_external_user'];

    System.runAs(externalUser)
    {
        List<Contact> listContacts2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact]; // **IS EMPTY (or contains only contacts created in the org, not 'testContact')**
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try using @isTest(SeeAllData=True)...and see if its working.

Comment: It may be worth sharing a bit of your code here and letting is take a look as to why your query might not be returning any results.

Comment: check the OWD for object

Comment: you have mentioned that insufficient permission error is coming it means that OWD is set as private. which apply same for test class that is why it is not returning those records in test class

Comment: If you are using the "with sharing" keyword in your test class it will not show the contact whereas the class that is being used when you are testing via the UI may not be using the with sharing keyword and thus returning results

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Yes, I'm using SeeAllData in order to be able to get my external user. So, you're right, if I have contacts in my org, I'll be able to see them in 'listContacts2'. But my question was to be able to see 'testContact', which was inserted in the test class, but is not in the org.

Comment: @Poet I edited my question with an extract of my code.

Comment: @Himanshu I think there's no need to check for OWD since the contact in the test class ('testContact'), and the one in the org are created by the same user (me, since I run the test), and the query is executed by the same user also (in the test class : runAs() method).

Comment: I don't think you need "SeeAllData" for Users. Users are special data in Salesforce tests and should be visible.

Comment: Are you sure it is not there? Does that user have access to "contacts" and is the external sharing model set to public for contacts? If not then they will not see it. Also, you should probably be limiting the query to use `where ID = :testContact.id`. If the contact was actually created and the user cannot see it when querying via the specific ID then it is a permissions issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because abandoned

Answer (score 1):

First thing's first, remove `@isTest(seeAllData=true)`. This should only be used in the rarest of circumstances.

You should also consider creating a user to use within the test, here's a simple bit of code on how to do that. It's not too dissimilar to how you create a test Contact, for instance:

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'The Profile'];
  User u = new User(
    Alias = 'testu',
    Email = 'test@example.com',
    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
    LastName = 'Test',
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
    ProfileId = p.Id,
    UserName='test@example.com'
  );

  System.runAs(u) {
    // Testing code goes here
  }
```

If you were to delete, deactivate or otherwise get rid of your test user, your test will break as a consequence. Doing this is much better practice and a lot more future-proof.

`List<Contact> listContacts2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact];` should work fine, but I would assert that you're expecting the query to return 1 contact, because you're not looking at all data and you've created 1 in the test method itself.

```
Integer listContacts2 = [SELECT Count() FROM Contact];

System.assertEquals(listContacts2, 1);
```

This should achieve the same thing.

If you're still having trouble, it may be worth logging in as an external user and running this query in Salesforce's Workbench whilst you're logged in as them and seeing what this returns. It may also be worth checking things like record type access and the contact generated may be of a type the external user doesn't have access to.